# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=c within 45 seconds

Tags: android-espresso

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 
>    cmp=com.makemytrip/com.mmt.travel.app.holiday.activity.HolidayLandingActivityNew
>   } within 45 seconds.

Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time?

I'm getting this error ,even when activity launch properly with given `Activity` name in `ActivityTestRule`.

Something is blocking espresso to find out that activity is idle or not.
this activity first hit sql data for fetching data,if data no found in sqlite then it makes fresh hit to server.

Comment: found solution for it, this error will persist until activity is not idle,means there is something blocking activity it may be some background services or progressive bar or any animation. it will be removed once fixing these type of issues.